# Webpack Encore function not recognized

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack

I try to use jquery cookie (`jquery.cookie.js`) in a separate file (`cookie.js`) with Symfony 5 and Webpack Encore but I get this error :

> TypeError: $.cookie is not a function

here is my `cookie.js` file :

```
//import cookie from './jquery.cookie';

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('cookiebar') === undefined) {
        $('body').append('<div class="cookie-bar" id="cookie-bar">En poursuivant votre navigation sur ce site, vous acceptez l\'utilisation de cookies pour réaliser des statistiques de visites anonymes. <a href="#">En savoir plus</a><div class="cookie_btn" id="cookie_accept">Ok</div><div class="cookie_btn-error" id="cookie_cancel">Refuser les cookies</div></div>');

        $('#cookie_accept').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#cookie-bar').fadeOut();

            $.cookie('cookiebar', 'viewed', {expires: 30 * 12});
        });

        $('#cookie_cancel').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#cookie-bar').fadeOut();

            $.cookie('cookiebar', 'viewed', {expires: 30 * 12});
            $.cookie('cookiecancel', '1', {expires: 30 * 12});
        });
    } else {
        if ($.cookie('cookiecancel') === undefined) {
            // Google analytics
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see I tried to import cookie function with : `import cookie from './jquery.cookie';`, the error wasn't there anymore but the script couldn't be executed.

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file :

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('www/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('checkUsername', './assets/js/checkUsername.js')
    .addEntry('checkParamUsername', './assets/js/checkParamUsername.js')
    .addEntry('jquery.cookie', './assets/js/jquery.cookie.js')
    .addEntry('cookie', './assets/js/cookie.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    .addStyleEntry('global', ['./assets/css/global.scss'])
    .addStyleEntry('login', ['./assets/css/login.css'])

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Also I load javascripts in my layout like this :

```
{% block javascripts %}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('build/jquery.cookie.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('build/cookie.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

i hop this will help you try to get the cookie like var =>

```
const cookie = require('jquery.cookie');
```

happy coding :

Comment: Thanks, I tried with `const cookie = require('./jquery.cookie');`. No more error but the code doesn't work, I tried to add some logs and nothing logs in the console.